# Newton–Raphson method with vector inputs in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

For this problem, we need to make use of the Newton-Raphson method to locate the roots of a particular function.
The code works for when the input is a single value, yet when the input is a vector, the answers aren't quite right.
For example, when `x=2` is an input, the value `2.5933` is returned and when `x=4`, `4.3215` is returned. Both these answers are correct, yet when I enter the vector `x = [2,4]`, it returns `[2.4106,4.4106]`.

```
f = @(x) [(17/77196).*x.^(3)-(15/12866).*x.^(2)+0.004];
fd = @(x) [(17/25732).*x.^(2)-(15/6433).*x];
x= %initial guess;
for i=1:10
x=x-f(x)/fd(x);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
f = @(x) [(17/77196).*x.^(3)-(15/12866).*x.^(2)+0.004];
fd = @(x) [(17/25732).*x.^(2)-(15/6433).*x];
x= [2, 4];
for i = 1:10
    x = x - f(x)./fd(x);
end
x
```

You were missing `.` after `f(x)` to make it an element-wise division.

Comment: I spent so much time trying to make sure the equations for f and fd were correctly entered i completely forgot about that statement, thanks so much man! :)